# Read number from a file and replace it with another number

Tags: c

```
12 23 34 45 56
34 23 56 21 43
12 57 98 34 12
```

The above is the content of a txt file.

With C, i can use `fgetc(myFile)` to get the first integer and store into an integer variable.

I will check whether it is 12.

if it is 12, i want to replace with 25. How do i exactly replace it a certain number.

How do i rewrite a certain part of it?

Or do i store every number into an array, replace all 12s with another numbers and overwrite the whole file??

Comment: Check `fgetc` reference, it will get you a character, not an integer. Also add 'homework' as tag.

Comment: Well, it can be done with `fgetc`, if done properly, but I doubt that that's the case here...

Comment: I know it is a character. but when i used an integer, it works.. so.. i skipped the character to integer part.

Comment: @littleadv, can fgetc() replace?

Comment: replace what? fgetc reads, it doesn't write.

Comment: i know.. i get the character (in my case, integer) with `fgetc()`, i can get the position of that character with `ftell()`.. now if that character (integer) is 12, i need to replace with 999. So, I need a function `fsth()` with probably 3 parameters(filename, position and value to replace with).

Comment: Yeah, I got it. You need to write that function yourself, it doesn't exist. Note, that if the size of the data differs, then you need to shift rest of the file, so rewriting the whole file would be easier. You have the list of the functions you need in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save result to another file, than renames it. This code opens `homework.txt`, replaces all 12 -> 25 and writes result to `homework_new.txt`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXBUF 42
#define HOMEWORKFILE "homework.txt"
#define HOMEWORKNEWFILE "homework_new.txt"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char buf[MAXBUF+1];
    char str[MAXBUF+1];
    FILE *hw;
    FILE *hw_new;
    int length;
    int i, j;
    int number;
    char is_first;
    int n_line = 0;

    hw = fopen(HOMEWORKFILE, "r");
    hw_new = fopen(HOMEWORKNEWFILE, "w");

    if (!hw)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "File not found: %s\n", HOMEWORKFILE);
        return 5;
    }

    while(!feof(hw))
        if (fgets(buf, MAXBUF, hw) != NULL)
        {
            length = strlen(buf);
            j = 0;
            str[0] = 0;
            is_first = 1;
            n_line++;
            /* parse string */
            for(i = 0; i < strlen(buf); ++i)
            {
                if (isblank(buf[i]) || buf[i] == '\0' || buf[i] == '\n')
                {
                    str[j] = 0;
                    number = atoi(str);

                    if (is_first)
                        is_first = 0;
                    else
                        fprintf(hw_new, " ");

                    if (number == 12)
                        fprintf(hw_new, "%d", 25);
                    else
                        fprintf(hw_new, "%d", number);

                    j = 0;
                }
                else if (isdigit(buf[i]))
                {
                    str[j++] = buf[i];
                }
                else
                {
                    fprintf(stderr, "bad input on line %d '%s'\n", n_line, buf);
                    return 100;
                }
            }
            fprintf(hw_new, "\n");

        }

    fclose(hw_new);
    fclose(hw);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's a small file , to overwrite the whole file is a good idea and easier.

If it's not limited in c language, you can try powerful tools like "sed" or some script language.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a list:

```
fgets
ftell
fseek
fputs
```

Note that you need to ensure the correct lengths of the data written, in order to overwrite exactly what you want.

Another option would be, as you said, to overwrite the whole file, then you also need

```
freopen
```